# ListTile with button

Tags: flutter, dart

I've got ListTile and button in leading property. Everything works fine however if the button is pressed then also tile onTap gesture is activated. Tile onTap doesn't trigger only the animation.

[image]

here is the code

```
ListTile(
   contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
   leading: IconButton(
       icon: Icon(Icons.check_circle),
     onPressed: () => print('select'),
   ),
   title: Text('TEST'),
   trailing: Icon(
      Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
  ),
  onTap: () => print('on tap'),
)
```

Any idea of how to get rid of the tile onTap effect from the leading area. The only way what comes to my mind is to use row in tile wrapped in gesture detector and get rid of the onTap but I'm hoping for some better solution if there is any

Comment: I think there's nothing you can do about it, there's no properties that can get rid of `onTap` effect in `ListTile`. Wrap it with `GestureDetector` is the way to go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option if you want to separate effects on the leading button and title area is to simply put flat button inside tile area and remove onTap. It is almost the same solution as you mentioned with gesture detector but at least you don't have to play with effects on that gesture detector.  I don't think there is any other option.

[image]

```
               ListTile(
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                leading: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.check_circle),
                  onPressed: () => print('select'),
                ),
                title: FlatButton(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  onPressed: () => print('on tap'),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text('TEST'),
                      Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios)
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
```

Comment: yes that's exactly what I wanted to achieve. I'll mark your answer as answered because I also don't think there is any better solution than this

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the spash, hover,highlight colors of the iconbutton   to transparent.

```
IconButton(
highlightColor: 
Colors.transparent,
splashColor: Colors.transparent,
hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
icon: Icon(Icons.check_circle),
onPressed: () => 
print('select'),
)
```

Comment: That will get rid of the button effect.. I need to get rid of the tile onTap effect from tile leading area

Answer (score 2):

See, if you don't want the `Ripple Effect` on your `leading`, I guess, `GestureDetector` is the one, which will help you. But you don't have to make the whole `ListTile` with `GestureDetector`, only `leading` is fine.

Please see the solution here:

```
       ListTile(
           contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
           leading: GestureDetector(
             onTap: () => print('icon tapped'),
             child: Icon(Icons.check_circle)
           ),
           title: Text('TEST'),
           trailing: Icon(
              Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
          ),
          onTap: () => print('on tap'),
       )
```

Now the above code, you can see the `leading` has `GestureDetector` only. Else, everything is same, and will work as expected.

Here is the result:

[image: RESULT GIF]

Comment: But that remove effect on the button which is same outcome as Frank answer. I was hoping to split these effects into leading area for button and rest of the tile area for tile onTap.

Comment: Hey @delmin, I did not get the perfect idea about your question, when I read this line **Any idea of how to get rid of the tile onTap effect from the leading area.**, hence, thought you only want to remove the effect from leading area. Anyways, hope you have got something out of it. **You have marked the correct answer**. Thanks for the upvote Delmin :)

Comment: You're welcome.. Your and Frank answer is also one way of doing it